# Do I need JSON schema validation for these APIS?

Tags: json

Here's the situation:
I have a number of APIs that are unit tested.
A swagger spec (swagger 2.0) is auto generated from code annotation on the APIs.

I'm tasked with validating the API endpoints.
In order to do this, I import the spec into Postman and generate a request collection to work with.

I'm currently considering validating the JSON responses against a schema in automated test scripts, but it this really useful? Because the collection I'm working with was generated based on swagger spec that in its turn was generated from the code.

Comment: Excellent question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postman collection generation from API just validates the API definition like:

1. Resource (End point)
2. HTTP Method
3. Parameters

It doesn't validate actual response.

imagine that the url of the generated collection was:

```
{{baseUrl}}/user?id=54750966
```

change baseUrl variable value as :

```
https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2 #
```

Now goto API and click validate , you can see that the API validation passes even tho we have entirely different baseURL.

Also validation is not real time , unless you go and explicitly validate collection against api definition we won't detect changes.

**Summary:**

1. Use collection generation for initial setup
2. Make sure you validate responses as generated collection doesn't do this for you

Comment: So Postman has a schema available but doesn't use it to validate actual request responses right? Really seems like a missed chance for Postman. So I guess I'll need to write my own schemas if I want schema validation for my responses.

Comment: you can raise it as a feature request: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues

Comment: I did some research on their existing feature requests and found these 2:

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/7020 & https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/9408.

I'm actually a bit amazed this feature doesn't get that much attention, because potential efficiency profit could be huge... please thumbs up!

Comment: That good to see , will keep tracking that .

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing you're also responsible for figuring out whether that Swagger documentation makes sense. It can be broken in various ways:

- missing (information about) authentication
- missing status codes that the endpoint in reality return
- query parameters marked as path parameters or vice versa
- spelling mistakes
- example request and response bodies that actually don't work or that are not consistent across endpoint

By coincidence I'm currently busy with testing APIs as well and at different times, I stumbled upon every one of the points above. Plus, a few times, the Swagger documentation was so wrong it couldn't even be generated properly, and so any paste and copy of the link into Postman proved useless.

To me, doing validation is not enough however I look at it. If you're tasked with this tiny subset of what you can do, it's still not enough to copy and paste the Swagger link into Postman and auto-generate a collection out of it. The difference between reality and Swagger could be bigger than what's acceptable. It's more likely that you'll need to figure out bits and pieces here and there and manually update the collection that was generated out of the Swagger.

> Because the collection I'm working with was generated based on swagger spec that in its turn was generated from the code.

Auto-generation doesn't mean it was generated correctly. In suprisingly many instances, it's not because ... well I suppose the code could be a mess in the first place, so then the Swagger doesn't make sense either. So if you take it as a source of truth, you're trapped from the very beginning.

Comment: Swagger as documentation is only used internally in the company I work for, and doesn't get that much prio because the user pool for that documentation is dozens instead of thousands. So even if I would raise some bug tickets for issues I found, it wouldn't get fixed. Besides that, you really have some valid points though, but a bit off topic for the question I'm asking.